# Clarifying POST-ing to a site

Tags: post

Say I were to post to a site using www.mysite.com?user=myuser does that simulate the submit button that is associated with that form? If so, what happens if there are a number of submit buttons in the form?

Also, if that button's html is like so `<input name="button" class="button" type="button" value="Save" onclick="javascript: submit()" disabled>` with the "disabled" attribute, does that mean I can't POST www.mysite.com?user=myuser/won't work?

```
<form name="Form" method="post" action="/thisAction.do">
    <input type="text" name="inquiryNo" maxlength="11" value="" onkeyup="javascript: checkNo()">
    <input name="buttonInquire" class="button" value="Inquire" onclick="javascript: submitInquire()" type="button">

    <!--Then comes a number of other inputs-->
    <input.../>
    <input.../>
    <input.../>

    <input name="modify" class="button" type="button" value="Save"
            onclick="javascript: submitModify()" disabled>

</form>
```

This is some sample code as it's work stuff which I am not allowed to share. So when I use the inquire action a new account successfully loads up and the details are presented on the page. The modify action is meant to 'modify' those details but it just returns the same details displayed on the page. I get no sort of feedback from anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* POST to a URL with a query string (the stuff after the `?`), and since you say you're using `urllib2` with a `data` argument, that's what happens.  The server can then read both the POST data and the query string and do whatever it wants, though most of the time they're merged together or the query string is ignored entirely.

`disabled` only stops you from clicking the button in the browser (and even then, you can just un-disable it with a tool like Firebug).  You can POST whatever you want to any URL you want; HTML can't stop you, though the server can still give you an error if it wants.

---

I think your problem is that "inquire" is the default action, and something's wrong with your POST.  So no matter what you send, the server isn't recognizing it and is falling back to "inquire".

It looks like the form is intended to send `modify=Save`.  Can you post the Python code you're actually running?

Comment: That seems to be clearing things up. Would you be able to provide some insight into my actual problem? Maybe some directions to take for debugging, or anything? So I have the one form and depending on the value of the'action' param that is POSTed (e.g. 'inquire', 'modify') it behaves differently. I seem to have the inquire working but the modify doesn't.

Comment: can you post code, or be more specific about what doesn't work?  what happens instead when you use "modify"?

Comment: Hmm...do you think it has something to do with the action of the form 'thisAction.do' not too sure what .do file do or are so I'm reading up on it now. (Made edit to question)

Comment: i guess you solved your problem  :)  for future reference, [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is a bit easier to use than `urllib2`

Comment: Yep. It was a number of minor issues in other unrelated parts of my code. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score -1):

No, what you actually typed in is a GET method.

There are 2 ways of submitting data: POST AND GET.

Post is by submitting data by using a form in a webpage that posts to another on the background, while GET is setting the data in the url itself like user=myuser.

Most of the times using a GET method (url query string) will not work if the web programmer actually is checking for a POST method. The same happens if the programmer is waiting for a GET request and you actually POST it.

However there is a php var called REQUEST which will work with GET and POST.

I'm no professional in PHP but because you had no answers at the moment I tried my best to explain it. Hopefully some expert will come along and explain it properly.

You edited your question while I was replying so you need someone to answer you on your second question.

Comment: Thanks. We'll I'm not actually using the user=myuser GET method, I'm using pythons Urllib2 `opener.open(url, data)`, which I think simulates the GET method. Also, using this method `www.mysite.com?user=myuser` on the same form different submit works.